# Display welcome message not shown in botframework webchat in React

Tags: botframework, web-chat

The welcome message is not shown when using direct line in botframework webchat. Im using botframework composer(not sdk).

```js
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import ReactWebChat, { createDirectLine } from 'botframework-webchat';

export default () => {
  const directLine = useMemo(() => createDirectLine({ token: 'YOUR_DIRECT_LINE_TOKEN' }), []);

  return <ReactWebChat
    directLine={
      directLine
    }
    userID="YOUR_USER_ID" />;
};
```

This is a common bug but i have no idea how to solve this in react together with botframework composer.

Comment: This is hard to answer without more details being provided. Some questions: Is the bot running locally in Composer or is it published? Does it have a "Greeting" trigger that responds to a `ConversationUpdate` activity? Is it only the welcome message that fails display or do other activities fail, as well? What version of Composer and Web Chat are you running?

Comment: Hi it works in the emulator and test web chat in azure and composer is already published but it does not work in when i put the react code above as suggested in the docs.

Comment: Can you include a link to the docs you are referencing? Could you answer the other questions above, as well? You can update your post with missing details so your response comment isn't long and hard to read. And, to clarify, it works without the React code and publishing and fails with the React code and publishing?

Comment: Yes it has a greeting trigger. Welcome message only shows after the user has typed something.(I want the welcome message to show without any user input) Everything else seems to work as intended. Im using botframework composer 1.4 with the latest react web chat from https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat . However in the emulator itself the greeting shows without any user input.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working? Have you verified that your Web Chat instance is working with other bots as you would like it to? Which version of Web Chat are you using? Lastly, have you tried with the latest Composer version, 2.1.0?